# How to generate a compact letter display for pairwise TukeyHSD

Tags: r, anova, tukey

I'm having trouble generating a compact letter display for my results. 
I've run an ANOVA followed by Tukey's HSD to generate the p values for each pair, but I do not know how (or if it is possible?) to assign letters to these p values to show which pairs are significant from each other.

`csa.anova<-aov(rate~temp*light,data=csa.per.chl)
summary(csa.anova)
TukeyHSD(csa.anova)`

This runs the tests I need, but I don't know how to assign letters to each p value to show which pairs are significant.

Comment: Your example is not reproducible, please edit the question with the output of `dput(head(csa.per.chl, 20))`. What are the letters you want to assign to what ranges of p-values? Say, `A: 0.00-0.05`, etc? What, exactly? Edit the question with that information, please.

Comment: What do you mean by "assign letters"? For others looking at this, here is an example using mtcars: `m <- mtcars
m$cyl <- as.factor(m$cyl); m$gear <- as.factor(m$gear)
m.anova<-aov(mpg~cyl*gear,data=m)
summary(m.anova)
TukeyHSD(m.anova)`

Comment: A CLD is a misleading graphic because it shows what comparisons were NOT found significant. So my answer is "just don't" and instead show a matrix of P values, or confidence intervals for differences of measure, or some other graphic that is not misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the `multcomp` package first. It can compute the Tukey HSD Test and returns an object that has `summary` and `plot` methods. The package also has a function (`cld`) to print the "compact letter display." As an example we can use the iris data set that comes with R:

```
library(multcomp)
data(iris)
iris.aov <- aov(Petal.Length~Species, iris)
iris.tukey <- glht(iris.aov, linfct=mcp(Species="Tukey"))
cld(iris.tukey)
#     setosa versicolor  virginica 
#        "a"        "b"        "c"
```

Answer (score 5):

### Find more details [here](https://schmidtpaul.github.io/dsfair_quarto/summaryarticles/compactletterdisplay.html).

```r
mod <- lm(Sepal.Width ~ Species, data = iris)

mod_means_contr <- emmeans::emmeans(object = mod,
                                    pairwise ~ "Species",
                                    adjust = "tukey")

mod_means <- multcomp::cld(object = mod_means_contr$emmeans,
                           Letters = letters)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = mod_means,
       aes(x = Species, y = emmean)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower.CL, 
                    ymax = upper.CL), 
                width = 0.2) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(aes(label = gsub(" ", "", .group)),
            position = position_nudge(x = 0.2)) +
  labs(caption = "Means followed by a common letter are\nnot significantly different according to the Tukey-test")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>